# Centering a position absolute element that has been cloned

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone a tooltip div and append it to the document body while also centering around it's original parent.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const tooltipActivator = document.querySelectorAll("[data-onsitetooltip]");
    for(let i = 0; i < tooltipActivator.length; i++) {
        if(tooltipActivator[i] != undefined) {
            let added = false;

            tooltipActivator[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e) {
                const clone = tooltipActivator[i].querySelector(".onsiteTooltip").cloneNode(true),
                      elemRect = tooltipActivator[i].getBoundingClientRect(),
                      offset_top = elemRect.top - document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top,
                      offset_left = elemRect.left;

                clone.style.visibility = "visible";
                clone.style.opacity = "1";
                clone.style.top = offset_top + parseInt(tooltipActivator[i].dataset.onsitetooltiptop) + "px";
                clone.style.left = offset_left + "px";
                clone.style.transform = "translateX(-"+tooltipActivator[i].offsetWidth/2+"px)";
                clone.style.pointerEvents = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(clone);
            });

            tooltipActivator[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {
                const tooltipToRemove = document.querySelectorAll("body > .onsiteTooltip");
                for(let z = 0; z < tooltipToRemove.length; z++) {
                    if(tooltipToRemove[z] != undefined) {
                        document.body.removeChild(tooltipToRemove[z]);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.onsiteTooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 25em;
    cursor: auto;
    background: #0c1633;
    padding: 1em;
    @include border-radius(0.25rem);
    @include box-shadow($shadow-big);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    @include transition(visibility 0s, opacity 0.2s linear);
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.myDiv { height: 100px; background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" data-onsitetooltip data-onsitetooltiptop="70">
    <div class="onsiteTooltip">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

The goal is to make it so when appended to the body, it should be below and centered around the element with the `data-onsitetooltip` property, without appending it as a child to that element.

Depending on the element that hold the tooltip, it works sometimes, but on other elements it sometimes isn't centered and misaligned.

Like this: http://prntscr.com/op0wuk

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: I've tried to set the offset left to 50% of the parent and then -50% on the tooltip like you would do in CSS but that did not work either.

Comment: To clarify: do you want the div to be centered around the mouse cursor but inside #myDiv?

Comment: @Jean-Paul No, I want the div to be centered horizontally in the red block as seen here: http://prntscr.com/op0wuk